# Get all badges with user progress if any

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a many to many relationship between users and achievements.  Table layout is similar to this.

```
users
-id
-first_name
-last_name
-email

acheivements
-id
-type-name
-description

achievement_user
-id
-acievement_id
-user_id
-is_complete (boolean)
-percentage_complete (integer)
-completed_at
```

I can get the bulk of the stuff I want such as all achievements with type = badge for a user that are in the pivot table.  I can also get a list of all the achievements that have type = badge.  Where I am stuck is trying to get all achievements with type = badge along with is_complete, percentage_complete, completed_at for that given user.  So if there are 8 total badges and they have started 3 of them I would want to return 8 records where 3 of them would have the information from the pivot table.  I know I could grab all badges and loop through them to add on additional information but I know there is a eloquent way that would be easier.

Thank for any help.

Comment: You need to learn about whereHas method which lets you query on relationshio while getting results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is in response to you recent comment.

To achieve what you want, I have introduced a new method on the `User` model called `achievementsblock`, which uses php `array_map` method.

I have not tested the code, but you should get the idea.

```
//in User model
public function achievements()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Achievements')->withPivot('is_complete', 'percentage_complete', 'completed_at');
    }

//in User model
public function achievementsblock()
    {
        $all_achievements = Achievement::all();
        return array_map(function($temp_achievement){
            $achievement_ids = $this->achievements()->pluck('id');
            $new_temp = new \stdClass();
            $new_temp->type_name = $temp_achievement->type_name;
            $new_temp->description = $temp_achievement->description;

            if(in_array($temp_achievement->id, $achievement_ids)){
                $user_achievement = $this->achievements()->where("achievements.id","=",$temp_achievement->id)->first();
                $new_temp->is_complete = $user_achievement->is_complete;
                $new_temp->percentage_complete = $user_achievement->percentage_complete;
                $new_temp->completed_at = $user_achievement->completed_at;

            }
            else {
                $new_temp->is_complete = 0;
                $new_temp->percentage_complete = 0;
                $new_temp->completed_at = null;
            }

            return $new_temp;
        }, $all_achievements);
    }
```

In your controllers, you can get the achievementsblock for a user as follows:

```
$user_achievement_blocks = User::first()->achievementsblock();
```

Comment: Had to make a couple of tweaks such as getting some results as array rather than objects.  Thanks for helping out.  Appreciate it.

Comment: Great! I am happy it was useful. Don't forget to come back to edit this answer with the changes when you are able.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to learn about whereHas method which lets you query on relationship while getting results**

**In User model**

// create achievements relationship

```
public function achievements()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Achievement::class)
              ->withPivot('is_complete', 'percentage_complete', 'completed_at');
}
```

//then query it like shown below.

```
$achievements= $user->achievements;
```

Read more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations)

Comment: Thanks I will look into this more in depth.  What you left here looks like it will get the user information and attach any achievements they have started.  I am looking to get all achievements and then attach any progress the user has for each one even if they have no progress records yet.  That way I can list all badges and show their progress if any.

Comment: Still only gets the ones the user started or has a record for in the pivot table.  Need to get all achievements and show progress even if there is none.  Idea is they land on achievement page and see all available achievements and any they have started will show their progress.

Answer (score 0):

On your `belongsToMany` relationship, use the withPivot function as follows:

```
//in User model
public function acheivements()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Acheivement')->withPivot('is_complete', 'percentage_complete', 'completed_at');
    }

//in Acheivement model
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withPivot('is_complete', 'percentage_complete', 'completed_at');
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.  I got that far myself but again doesn't solve what i am trying to do.  If I have 3 achievements (id =1, 2 & 3) in my achievement table and in the achievement_user table the user has two records as they have started or completed 2 achievements (id = 1 & 2).  When I call user->achievements it will only return the 2 achievements.  I still want it to return all 3 achievements just the withPivot fields would be blank or null for the achievement with id = 3.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: You mean the code I provided doesn't do that? Then, kindly explain further.

Comment: If I have 4 records in achievement table and I have 3 records for a user in the achievement_user table as they have started 3 of the achievements.  When I call $user->achievements I only get the 3 achievements they have started.  I am trying to get all achievements so in this case I want all 4 achievements and then the users progress even if there is no progress.  The idea is to bring user to achievement page to show then all possible achievements they can pursue.  When listing the achievements I want to show progress for that user if any.